# How do you compute the sample variance between the difference in means of two samples?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I am given the means for four samples $x_1,...x_4$ and a sample covariance matrix S that’s size $4\times 4$.

How do I compute the sample covariance for $x_1-x_2$? I assumed it would just be $s_{11}-s_{22}$, but I am not getting the correct value.

Comment: Both samples does have the same size? And you want to calculate $cov(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: Yes, both have n=50 observations but I am not given the actual observations. Just their means and the sample variance- covariance matrix. I assumed cov(x1,-x2)=cov(x1)-cov(x2) but my answer does not match the correct value

Comment: One more question You need two arguments for the covariance. You want to calculate the covariance of $x_1-x_2$ and ...? Or maybe the covariance of $x_1$ and $-x_2$.

Comment: I need to find simultaneous confidence intervals, in this case the interval for x1-x2 so I’m assuming it’s cov(x1,-x2) but in actuality it’s cov(x1-x2)

Comment: You need to find $var(x_1-x_2)=var(x_1)+var(x_2)-2cov(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: Thank you, that was one of my original attempts but I was worried I approached it incorrectly since I was given sample variance so I changed my technique

Comment: You're welcome. It is all fine now?

Comment: Yep, thanks again

Comment: That´t nice, Jorge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are given a $S \in \Bbb{R^{4 \times 4}}$ covariance matrix, then each element will provide you with the variance between $x_i$ and $x_j$.
$$Cov(x_i,x_j) =s_{ij}$$
where $S = [s_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^4$.

Another important fact to note is that $Var(x_i-x_j) = Var(x_i) + Var(x_j) - 2\ Cov(x_i,x_j)$. (See more basic variance properties [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties).)

And lastly, $Var(x_i) = Cov(x_i,x_i) = s_{ii}$.

Now putting these all together:

$$Var(x_i-x_j) = Var(x_i) + Var(x_j) - 2\ Cov(x_i,x_j) = s_{ii} + s_{jj} - 2\ s_{ij}$$

Or, since the covariance matrix is symmetric:

$$Var(x_i-x_j) = Var(x_i) + Var(x_j) - 2\ Cov(x_i,x_j) = s_{ii} + s_{jj} - s_{ij} - s_{ji}.$$

And specifically,

$$Var(x_1-x_2) = Var(x_1) + Var(x_2) - 2\ Cov(x_1,x_2) = s_{11} + s_{22} - 2\ s_{12}.$$